# Use XPath with condition to get array values from XML

Tags: xpath

I would like to get data from `EventParameters` array using `XPath`, but I don't know how to get a parameter where `Name` is equal to something... Could anyone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Event>
    <EventParameters>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>PKAN_ID</Name>
            <Value>2466</Value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>REPS_ID</Name>
            <Value>4</Value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <Name>REPS_ID_OLD</Name>
            <Value>5</Value>
        </Parameter>
    </EventParameters>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) on the `Parameter` element:

```
/Event/EventParameters/Parameter[Name='PKAN_ID']
```

This returns the parameter named `PKAN_ID`. To get its value:

```
/Event/EventParameters/Parameter[Name='PKAN_ID']/Value
```